# Apply DOM queries on C# webresponse

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dom

I am creating web request and having webresponse object with me in C#.

Is there any way that I can apply DOM queries (`document.getElementByClass('')` etc ) on web response string?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the DOM queries in your server-side code, i.e., from C#?

Comment: yes, I want to query that from server side

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can query nodes with XPath or Linq.